# Loading Aync Gifs to Scrolling CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uicollectionview, gif

The gifs I fetch from the `Giphy API` returns correctly and in fact loads properly to the `uicollectionview` using `SwiftGif`.

The issue only surfaces when I scroll immediately, the `uicollectionview` loads either duplicate gifs or gifs that are in the incorrect index. I understand this is probably a timing issue with the delay in rendering the gif and loading the gif to the cell.

Any guidance would be appreciated as asynchronous operations are something I'm still unfamiliar with..

Also any best practices for handling gifs would be appreciated if there are any flags in the code below, specifically to support speed/memory usage.

I've tried placing various checks like seeing if the initially passed gif url is the same at the point it's loaded, and also setting the image to nil every time `cellForItemAt` is fired, but to no avail. Couldn't find existing threads that clearly resolved this issue as well.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var gifCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var gifUrls: [String] = []
var gifImages: [String: UIImage] = [:]

func fetchGiphs() {
    let op = GiphyCore.shared.search("dogs", media: .sticker) { (response, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            print("Giphy Fetch Error: ", error)
            return
        }

        if let response = response, let data = response.data, let pagination = response.pagination {
            for result in data {
                if let urlStr = result.images?.downsized?.gifUrl {
                    self.gifUrls.append(urlStr)
                }
            }
            if !self.gifUrls.isEmpty {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.gifCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("No Results Found")
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return gifUrls.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! GifCell

    let passedUrlString = gifUrls[indexPath.item]
    cell.imageView.image = nil

    if let image = gifImages[gifUrls[indexPath.item]] {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.imageView.image = image
            cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
        }
    } else {
        cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = false
        cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            let gifImage = UIImage.gif(url: self.gifUrls[indexPath.item])
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if passedUrlString == self.gifUrls[indexPath.item] {
                    cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                    cell.imageView.image = gifImage
                    self.gifImages[self.gifUrls[indexPath.item]] = gifImage
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
}


class GifCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, the cell may be reused when image loading completed.

You need to check if it is reused or not. Your `passedUrlString == self.gifUrls[indexPath.item]` does not work for this purpose.

Maybe, giving a unique ID for each cell would work:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! GifCell
    let uniqueId = Int.random(in: Int.min...Int.max) //<-practically unique
    cell.tag = uniqueId //<-

    cell.imageView.image = nil

    if let image = gifImages[gifUrls[indexPath.item]] {
        cell.imageView.image = image
        cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
    } else {
        cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = false
        cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            let gifImage = UIImage.gif(url: self.gifUrls[indexPath.item])
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if cell.tag == uniqueId { //<- check `cell.tag` is not changed
                    cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                    cell.imageView.image = gifImage
                    self.gifImages[self.gifUrls[indexPath.item]] = gifImage
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Assuming you are not using `tag` for other purposes.

Please try.

Comment: it works! but...for some reason the collectionView freezes on initial load at the very beginning if you try to scroll and im unsure why + how to solve? is this a threading issue, if so, i thought the DispatchQueue.global.async took care of that? hope you can help me better understand and optimize the apparent laboring performance.. @OOPer

Comment: @Chris, thanks for reporting. But I cannot find what's the reason exactly in your case. One possible reason might be your app is sending too many requests simultaneously, which may happen with your original code. Unless more info about what's happening, I cannot be help of you.

Comment: thanks the the quick reply! im happy to give whatever more context i can give! the above code though is essentially all the code there is though...fetching from the Giphy API of gif url strings and then downloading and assigning the gifs to a cell's uiimageview via cellForItem. @OOPer

Comment: @Chris, As far as I checked the source code of SwiftGif, it has some fault in pointer handling, which may be causing the issue. Try to remove the part using SwiftGif and see what happens.

Comment: i removed it and the collectionView scrolls fine now, but that's probably because consecutive intensive downloading tasks aren't being taken place anymore. im using SwiftGif to download and create the gif images, is there a workaround here? im unsure how one goes about better optimizing the workload as i do need the outputed gif images.. @OOPer

Comment: @Chris, I do not recommend and do not want to help, to use such buggy library. You should better find another way around for loading images.

Comment: i switched to the FLAnimatedImage library and it doesn't freeze anymore, thank you for your correspondence throughout this.

Comment: Happy to hear that. May your app be great.